# Crash on doInBackground() in android?

Tags: android

Application crash, response came but application is crash and giving like this...
my code find using url
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nu7uazz8yp3w3cu/GetCompanyAnalyticRequestTask.java?dl=0

- My call is like this

  ```
  callAnalyticAPI(mPreferences.getString(PrefrennceList.ADMIN_UID, ""), mPreferences.getString(PrefrennceList.CID, ""), groupJsonArray.toString().trim(), "summary", Constant.GRAPH_SUMMARY_START_DATE, Constant.GRAPH_SUMMARY_END_DATE, mPreferences.getString(PrefrennceList.COMPANY_ACCESS_TOKEN, ""));
  ```
- Execute method is

  ```
  try {
          mGetCompanyAnalyticRequestTask.execute(uid, cid, Utility.stringEncode(gids.toString().trim()), reptype, startDate, endDate, companyaccessToken);
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  ```
- Error

  ```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=6
                                                                            at com.sociosquare.socioadvocacy.service.GetCompanyAnalyticRequestTask.doInBackground(GetCompanyAnalyticRequestTask.java:38)
                                                                            at com.sociosquare.socioadvocacy.service.GetCompanyAnalyticRequestTask.doInBackground(GetCompanyAnalyticRequestTask.java:24)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
  ```

Comment: Provide your code...

Comment: please paste your code..

Comment: you are doing some logical error in your doInBackground() 
please provide your code.

Comment: @anddevmanu please check link to find my code

Comment: Please don't just link to your code off-site. You need to provide the code in the question itself. Anyway, it's a basic `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You're trying to access 7 items in the array in `doInBackground()`, but you've only passed 6.

Comment: @MikeM. please check, my call i passed 7 items in api call

Comment: That's a separate method call. Look at the `execute()` call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Index out of bounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458295/java-index-out-of-bounds)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this line is causing problems. Probably you are not passing enought parameters in AsyncTask.execute().

```
return CompanyAnalytic(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3], params[4], params[5], params[6]);
```

Comment: my execute call is    mGetCompanyAnalyticRequestTask.execute(uid, cid, Utility.stringEncode(gids.toString().trim()), reptype, startDate, endDate, companyaccessToken);

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in 
you are sending less values in params.so thats why it is giving crash.you are sending array  of size 6, so remove params[6] from your return statement.

```
 return CompanyAnalytic(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3], params[4], params[5]);
```